# How Can Declare Query in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

Can I declare a query in the laravel blade? cause in CI you can use like this code

```
$cek_tiket= $this->db->query("SELECT * from tiket WHERE tanggal='$tgl' AND id_jadwal='$jadwal->id_jadwal'");
```

Comment: Typically, such a query would be in the controller, and the *results* passed **to** the view. While direct queries can certainly be run a Laravel view, it's typically a sign you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** query in the view, but it is a BAD PRACTICE.

You would do something like this (untested):

```php
<div class="ticket-number">
    {{
    DB::table('tiket')
        ->where('tangal', $tgl)
        ->where('id_jadwal', $jadwal->id_jadwal)
        ->first()
        ->id;
    }}
</div>
```

Like I said though, this is NOT a good way to do it.

Instead, in your controller get the data from your model and pass it to the view.

Comment: here i'm try to doing this code 

forech($jadwal as $jadwal){
     $tiket=(select * from tiket where tanggal=$date and id_jadwal=$jadwal->id_jadwal);

If($tiket->nums_row()<=70){
 Echo “there no data”;
}
}

because that i'm ask how to run the query inside the view, but can you tell me how to doing this code without run the code inside the view ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but not recommended.

```
   @php
       $cek_tiket = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * from tiket WHERE tanggal='$tgl' AND id_jadwal='$jadwal->id_jadwal'"));
   @endphp
```

Then use it liek this `{{$cek_tiket}}`

Comment: here i'm try to doing this code 

forech($jadwal as $jadwal){
     $tiket=(select * from tiket where tanggal=$date and id_jadwal=$jadwal->id_jadwal);

If($tiket->nums_row()<=70){
 Echo “there no data”;
}
}

because that i'm ask how to run the query inside the view, but can you tell me how to doing this code without run the code inside the view ?